# How do I position bar chart labels at the "base" of bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a horizontal bar chart with labels on the bars, at their "bases"

```
dummy <- USArrests
dummy$state <- rownames(USArrests)

ggplot(
  data = dummy,
  aes(
    x = state,
    y = Murder
  )
) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity"
  ) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = state
    ),
    position = position_dodge(1)
  )
```

This gives me a chart where the labels are at each bar's "tip." [image]

How do I move those labels to the "base" of each bar? The left side of each state's name should be at the left side of the bars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were using dodging to try to help with the positioning it's not necessary. Also, `geom_col()` saves you some typing:

```
library(hrbrthemes) # devtools::install_git("https://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/hrbrthemes")
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
data.frame(
  state = state.name,
  murder = sample(1000, length(state.name)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) -> xdf

ggplot(xdf, aes(state, murder)) +
  geom_col(fill = "#2b2b2b") +
  geom_text(
    aes(y = 0, label = state), 
    color = ft_cols$yellow, hjust = 0
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand=c(0,0), label=scales::comma, position = "right"
  ) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum_rc(grid="X") +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

But, consider using `geom_segment()` which gives you a bit more control and doesn't need flipping:

```
ggplot(xdf, aes(murder, state)) +
  geom_segment(
    aes(xend=0, yend=state), 
    size = 5, color = "#2b2b2b"
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = 0, label = state), 
    color = ft_cols$yellow, hjust = 0
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    expand=c(0,0), label=scales::comma, position = "top"
  ) +
  labs(y= NULL) +
  hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum_rc(grid="X") +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, never tried `geom_segment`. Do you know if it's useful for making grouped bar charts? (Like this: https://www.infocaptor.com/help/drex_vertical_group_bar_custom_7.png)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```
+ geom_text(aes(label = state,y = 0),
          position = position_dodge(1),
          hjust = 0)
```